# How small the Earth should be for it to become a black hole?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, event-horizon, earth

How small would the earth have to be squashed so that it would become a black hole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a [Schwarzschild Radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) based solely on total mass, i.e. $R_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$.  If you plug in the mass of the earth, the radius is about 9 mm --- which is how small you would have to compress it to make a black-hole.

Comment: why is it not necessary to account for relativistic effects?

Comment: @CognisMantis The Schwarzschild Radius **is** a relativistic effect.  What else might one account for?

Comment: oh, sorry. I had the impression that the derivation was to have mv^2/2=GMm/r, which magically gets the right answer. Why is it not justified to use mc^2(L-1)=GMm/r, but when I do that, I get that the radius is zero. Why must we use the field equations?

Comment: @CognisMantis The Einstein field equations in vacuum is satisfied by the Schwarzschild black hole solution.

Comment: This answer is wrong since the Earth is rotating.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is $r = \frac{r_{s}+\sqrt{r_{s}^{2}-4a^{2}}}{2}$

where $r_{s} = \frac{2GM}{c^{2}}$ and a=$\frac{J}{Mc}$